# Datatype integer. Keep incrementing not restarting. -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to capture total_time_paused in my app. I'm doing this by taking two datetimes and storing the seconds between them in total_time_paused. Right now it restarts the data everytime. I actually want it to increment not restart. Here is my code.

```
def total_paused_time
  (timekeeper.paused_at - timekeeper.unpaused_at).abs.round
end
```

So here I take the paused_at datetime and the unpaused_at datetime And I get the seconds between them. I then take that time and pass it in as an integer attribute call total_time_paused. This works but everytime I pause and unpause it resets the total_time_paused attribute when I actually want it to increase the existing number stored. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you adding `total_paused_time` to `total_time_paused` variable?

Comment: Instead of doing this `(timekeeper.paused_at - timekeeper.unpaused_at).abs.round` you can achieve the same using `timekeeper.paused_at.to_i - timekeeper.unpaused_at.to_i` in this case even if it goes nil it will escape from exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to post more about your total time logic but here is the issue I see.

Each time you calculate the total paused time:

```
def total_paused_time
  (timekeeper.paused_at - timekeeper.unpaused_at).abs.round
end
```

You are overwriting the previous value.

You should have a Column that stores your total paused time. What you want to do is add to that column the total amount of seconds not set it.

```
def total_paused_time
  total_seconds = (timekeeper.paused_at - timekeeper.unpaused_at).abs.round
  # add the new paused seconds to the previous
  self.total_paused_time += total_seconds
end
```

You can also do it the rails way:

```
def total_paused_time
  total_seconds = (timekeeper.paused_at - timekeeper.unpaused_at).abs.round
  # add the new paused seconds to the previous
  self.increment!(:total_paused_time, by= total_seconds)
end
```

The advantage of using "increment!" instead of "+=" is that "increment!" adds and saves the records. "+=" only increments the number but doesn't save it. You will have to call .save of place it in a before_save filter.